# How to bring all windows to front when one of them is brought to front?

Tags: wpf, window, activation

All my windows shares the same base WindowBase class.
I have

```
        this.Activated += WindowBase_Activated;
```

and

```
    void WindowBase_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_bActivating)
        {
            _bActivating = true;
            activateAllWindows();
            Activate();
            _bActivating = false;
        }
    }
    private void activateAllWindows()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("triggered");
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.IsVisible && (window as WindowBase)._bActivating == false && window.WindowState==WindowState.Normal)
            {
                window.Activate();
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working but extremely slow.
However I find "triggered" printed more or less 100 times when the application is startup.

All I want to do is to bring all windows to front while stack the one that I clicked from taskbar to the top.
How can I improve?

P.S. I'm not bring my windows up from minimized. Just to front.
And I can do this in Qt since there is a func called stackUnder of QWidget (as a window)

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it with a trick.
in activeAllWindows I just used

```
                window.Topmost = true;
                window.Topmost = false;
```

to prevent it produce a activated event.